# How can I make the list view scroll 360 using flutter

Tags: list, flutter, listview, scroll

I have list view and I need it scroll 360ْ
I mean when last item finish the first item start.

Comment: There is a package currently doing what you want https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_listview

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have list of `items`. You can do this.

```
 ListView.builder(builder: (context, index) {
      final actualIndex = index % items.size();
      return YourWidget(items[actualIndex]);
    },
    itemCount: 9999999999,
  );
```

Comment: i have 5 items and when i scroll the list (i need the items appear like circle  ) not stopped

Comment: like wheel on iOS pickers? If yes, try out this widget
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPicker-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider using ListWheelScrollView with looping delegate.

```
ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
        itemExtent: 30,
        childDelegate: ListWheelChildLoopingListDelegate(
          children: List<Widget>.generate(
            10, (index) => Text('$index'),
          ),
        ),
      )
```